# What is best practice to websocket reconnect in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, websocket, react-hooks

I have react app with ticket polling (ticket is part of link for websocket connection). Then I pass websocket object to another component, because only this (another) component should make `.send()`
  After user login or logout I need to get new ticket for new connection because server has specialized data for logged users.
  How should I organize my code for this task?

I tried to reassign ws object after login/logout but got "Assignments to the 'ws' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render" error
  I can't store ws assignment inside useEffect hook because then i not be able to pass it as prop
  I'm although using Redux as you can see

```js
const App = () => {
  const { ticket, isLoggedIn } = useSelector(state => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestTicket = () => {
      fetch('http://some/api/websocket', {
        method: 'POST'
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(ticket => {
          dispatch(setTicket(ticket));
        });
    };
    requestTicket();
  }, [dispatch]);

  let ws = new WebSocket('ws://socket/' + ticket);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://some/api/websocket', {
      method: 'POST'
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(ticket => {
        ws = new WebSocket('ws://socket/' + ticket);
      });
  }, [isLoggedIn, ws]);

  ws.onmessage = e => {
    dispatch(setData(JSON.parse(e.data)));
  };

  return <Child ws={ws} />;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap WebSocket connection and onmessage in a function.
check if WebSocket is close, callback the function. Also may use setTimeout. 
Example :

```
function connect(){
  //WebSocket Connection
  //WebSocket onmessage
}
conn.onclose = evt => {
console.log('Socket is closed.Reconnect will be attempted in 10 second.', evt.reason);
    setTimeout(() => connect(), 10000);
};
```

Comment: 1. WebSocket will not be defined in <Child />
2. Server dont close WebSocket. I just start connection with new url

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this way

```
function connect() {
  var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
  ws.onopen = function() {
    // subscribe to some channels
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        //.... some message the I must send when I connect ....
    }));
  };

  ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Message:', e.data);
  };

  ws.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log('Socket is closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 1 second.', e.reason);
    setTimeout(function() {
      connect();
    }, 1000);
  };

  ws.onerror = function(err) {
    console.error('Socket encountered error: ', err.message, 'Closing socket');
    ws.close();
  };
}

connect();
```